# How to configure JavaScript XMPP Client(JSXC) to website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, ejabberd

I new to xmpp, need to configure chat in my web application, don't know how to configure xmpp in web application and, added my domain to ejabberd, and using JavaScript XMPP Client(JSXC) for chat, when i trying to login chat it will display error message like

"BOSH server NOT reachable or misconfigured.

Your server responded with "404 Not Found". Please check if your BOSH server is running and reachable via http://example.com/http-bind/."

please suggest me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time you configure that, probably the configuration of BOSH in ejabberd and in your client are not yet perfect. This tutorial is for an old ejabberd, and another BOSH client, but it may give you some hint: https://www.ejabberd.im/jwchat-localserver/index.html